# Writing file on system partition

Tags: android, filesystems, root

I am trying to write a file, generated by my app, onto the system partition. As I can not create an FileOutputStream inside my app I create the file in the data directory of my app, correct the permissions and then move it to the system partition.

At the moment the code below misses the writable remount of /system - for testing purposes I have performed this step successfully via `adb remount` - therefore this should not be the problem.

The app also gets successfully root permissions.

But the code below does not work. It only creates the file but does not move it to the system partition. What's my mistake?

```
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("myfile.test", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
File f = getFileStreamPath("myfile.test");
writeDataToOutputStream(out);
out.close();
String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
r.exec("su");
// Waiting here some seconds does not make any difference
r.exec(new String[] { "chown", "root.root", filename });
r.exec(new String[] { "chmod", "644", filename });
r.exec(new String[] { "mv", filename, "/system/myfile.test" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found how to execute multiple commands with root permissions. The trick is to send all commands to the one su process:

```
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("myfile.test", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
File f = getFileStreamPath("myfile.test");
writeDataToOutputStream(out);
out.close();
String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process suProcess = r.exec("su");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes("chown 0.0 " + filename + "\n");
dos.flush();
dos.writeBytes("chmod 644 " + filename + "\n");
dos.flush();
dos.writeBytes("mv " + filename + " /system/myfile.test\n");
dos.flush();
```

The only thing left (not include din the code above) is to make `/system` writable.
May be one additional command like `mount -o rw,remount /system` is sufficient - will test that.

Comment: And what is please this writeDataToOutputStream(out) function ? Can you please post it ?

Comment: That is the part where my application writes data into the myfile.test. That is application specific and is therefore of no interest here.

Comment: I am trying to write to /system/app using your piece of code. I have installed my app as a system app (by copying it to /system/app manually). It has sharedUserId=system, and it is signed with platform key.

I got 'java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)' on first call to writeBytes(). 

Could you please provide any clues on resolving this? What am I missing?

Comment: @Chaitanya did u solved your problem? if so please explain how you solved. Am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that only the first call to `Runtime.exec()`:

```
r.exec("su");
```

acheives root.  The docs for `Runtime.exec()` say that each invocation runs as a separate process.  So all of the subsequent calls to `exec`, for `chown`, `chmod`, `mv` all run with the permissions of the current app process - and hence fail.

You might be able to write a small shell script, then pass the shell script as an argument to `su`.  Then all the commands would get run with root permission.